# Fast algorithm to clear a board in Go

Tags: c, baduk

I am currently writing some code to deal with Go boards. A Go board is represented as an array of colors. The array has `size` × `size` entries and represents a two-dimensional square board.

```
enum color {
    EMPTY,
    BLACK,
    WHITE,
};

struct go_board {
    unsigned int size;
    enum color intersections[];
};
```

When `enum color player` moves, the following procedure applies: (See [rules](http://senseis.xmp.net/?TrompTaylorRules))

1. [...]
2. a point P, not colored C, is said to reach C, if there is a path of (vertically or horizontally) adjacent points of P's color from P to a point of color C.
3. Clearing a color is the process of emptying all points of that color that don't reach empty.
4. [...]
5. A move consists of [...] clearing the opponent color, and then clearing one's own color.

I am looking for a fast (in terms of noth computational complexity and actual speed) algorithm to clear a board. Can you help me?

Comment: Have you measured your "slow" method and determined it is a bottleneck in your application? First: make it work correctly; don't worry about performance.

Comment: @pmg The "slow" method I am thinking of is so uggly that I have not yet tested it. The computational complexity is O(nˆ4) where n is the size of the board.

Comment: @pmg I am interested in how to solve it efficiently, not just in how to solve it at all. If just solving a problem would be sufficient, we could just use stoogesort all the time...

Comment: @pmg Also, consider a Go AI. It has to clear the board after every move. Clearing the board therefor might be a bottleneck.

Comment: I welcome the baduk tag :) But it should maybe have been weiqi or weichi (as the game probably originated in china)... anyway, less ambiguous than "go".

Comment: @Olivier The problem with weiqi is the ambiguity in the spelling. Anyway, we could make tag synonyms.

Comment: @FUZxxl: If you'd like to clear the board after every move, incremental algorithms would be much more useful.

Comment: @thiton Maybe it is a good idea to keep track of a groups liberties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use image processing's flood-filling algorithms. First, seed with the empty points and fill all positions that are white or empty; all non-filled positions with white stones will be dead. Repeat with black.

Comment: This seems to be like a O(n²) algorithm and looks pretty nice. I am gonna look at this. Thank you!

Comment: this could work but I have to admit I'm not sure I understand. And it may not work : in Go, some groups are unconditionally alive (2 or more eyes, or several false eyes between interconnected groups), some others are "interdependently" alive (seki, ...). I'm not sure this can trivially be put back to a simple filling algorithm.

Comment: @Olivier I just ask about groups that shall be removed because they have no liberties left.  More calculations are not needed in my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to each group on the board, and keep track of their liberties. For each added stone, you just merge/update at most 4 groups together. Is it me or this sounds like O(k)?:)

(edited)

Comment: How will this help me? A Go board is not exactly sparse.

Comment: Indeed, I answered too fast orz Let me edit my answer.